# Dividing page into two sections

Tags: html

I have the below html code. What I need to do is split wuiInPageNav into two sections. LeftArea and wuiMainPageNav and they need to be side by side all the time. LeftAre div will hold my jstree nodes and wauiMainPageNave div will hold my charts and data etc. When I do the following, left goes left and wuiMainPageNav goes to the right. But when I resize the browser window, make it smaller, wuiMainPageNave goes down to the botttom. How do I make sure that LeftArea is always on the left and wuiMainPageName is always on the right, regardles of the browser window and size?missing here. Any ideas?

```
div id="wuiLeftArea">
        <div id="wuiLefthandNavRoot">
            <h2 class="wui-hidden">Section Navigation</h2>
            <h3 class="wui-navigation-title">Applicaion</h3>
            <div id=tree></div>
        </div>
</div>


<div id=wuiMainArea>
    <div id=wuiMainContent>
        <div id=wuiInpageNav>

                <div id="top_chart" class="center"> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
#wuiInpageNav {left:300px; float:right; width:1200px !important; overflow:hidden; }
div#wuiLeftArea{
    float: left;
    width: 16.25em;
    background-color: #f2f4f5; 
    padding-top: .5833em; 
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Looks around for "2 column layout" and you'll find your answer

Comment: Additionally, your inline styles are invalid. The styles on `left` should not have a comma and `float` on `main` must be set to "left" or "right" - not "top left".

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Make sure you don't do your CSS inline:
http://jsfiddle.net/FE79R/1/

HTML

```
<div id=wuiMainArea>
    <div id=wuiMainContent>
        <div id=wuiInpageNav>
            <div id="left">
                <div id="tree">tree</div>
            </div>
            <div id=main>
                <div id="top_charts" class="center"> </div>
                    <div class="main1">
                        <div id="top_chart1" class="center">top chart 1</div>
                        <div id="top_chart2" class="center">top chart 2</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
#wuiInpageNav { width:300px; overflow:hidden; }
#left { width:100px; float:left; position:relative; background-color:#f2f4f5;}
#main { width:200px; float:left; background-color:orange;}
```

Comment: this is great. One small problem. When I lower the browser size, main dive goes down the left div again. I need left dive on the left and main div on the right at all times.

Comment: Give #wuiInpageNav a hard px value, for example, #wuiInpageNav { width:400px; overflow:hidden; }

Comment: I am really sorry for this but I need to get this working and it is not. I will modify the original post.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle and the posted code. Seems to work in jsfiddle.

Comment: just updated my original post.